# Finder icon no longer in first position pressing CMD-TAB

Tags: finder, icon

It's been quite a while (and probably it started happening under 10.13) that, pressing CMD-TAB to switch among open applications, the Finder icons is no longer shown in first position, as it had always been.

Now it is in random position and this is uncomfortable.

I searched the web a lot but nothing was similar to this issue. I'm almost sure it depends on some plist preference file, but I cannot go randomly deleting them and see what happens (even saving the original ones).

Or maybe there's a terminal command to fix the issue.

Any clues?

Comment: The order is most-recently-used, starting with the current application at the left. Not sure this is configurable though.

Comment: But this is not like it was in the past. Before, we always had Finder in first position, then the other ones with the most recent from the 2nd position onwards.